# Eliminating MonadReader constraint using runReaderT

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers

I have been watching [Refactoring some Haskell code to use MTL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Af2ZUK3Z4U) which refactors some Haskell code to make use of the typeclasses from the mtl package.

The code includes a `postReservation` function with the following signature:

```
postReservation :: ReservationRendition -> IO (HttpResult ())
```

The implementation of the `postReservation` function makes use of three additional functions with the following signatures:

```
readReservationsFromDB :: ConnectionString -> ZonedTime -> IO [Reservation]
getReservedSeatsFromDB :: ConnectionString -> ZonedTime -> IO Int
saveReservation :: ConnectionString -> Reservation -> IO ()
```

In the video, the signatures of the three functions are refactored so that they return a generic type with a `MonadIO` constraint i.e.

```
readReservationsFromDB :: (MonadIO m) => ConnectionString -> ZonedTime -> m [Reservation]
getReservedSeatsFromDB :: (MonadIO m) => ConnectionString -> ZonedTime -> m Int
saveReservation :: (MonadIO m) => ConnectionString -> Reservation -> m ()
```

I understand that doing this makes the functions more flexible as they no longer depend on a concrete monad type or a specific monad transformer stack configuration. I also understand that the `postReservation` function can still make use of these functions without any changes to its type signature because it has a return type of IO which is an instance of the MonadIO typeclass.

Next, the three functions are refactored to include a `MonadReader` constraint so that the connection string does not need to be explicitly passed around i.e.

```
readReservationsFromDB :: (MonadReader ConnectionString m, MonadIO m) => ZonedTime -> m [Reservation]
getReservedSeatsFromDB :: (MonadReader ConnectionString m, MonadIO m) => ZonedTime -> m Int
saveReservation :: (MonadReader ConnectionString m, MonadIO m) => Reservation -> m ()
```

The signature of the `postReservation` function is also updated to include the `MonadIO` and `MonadReader` constraints i.e

```
postReservation :: (MonadReader ConnectionString m, MonadIO m) => ReservationRendition -> m (HttpResult ())
```

The presenter of the video goes on to make a concrete version of the `postReservation` function called `postReservationIO` in order to eliminate the typeclass constraints. A broken version of the `postReservationIO` function is written to demonstrate that it cannot just make use of the `postReservation` function because the `IO` type returned by the `postReservationIO` function is not an instance of the `MonadReader` typeclass.

We are then told that in order to eliminate the `MonadReader` constraint from the `postReservationIO` function we need to make use of the `runReaderT` function which is where the video loses me.

At about 15:00, the `postReservationIO` function is refactored to look like this

```
postReservationIO :: ReservationRendition -> IO (Httpresult ())
postReservationIO req = runReaderT (postReservation req) connStr
```

The `runReaderT` function has a type signature of `ReaderT k r m a -> r -> m a` which I'm reading as a function that takes some concrete `ReaderT` type and some value of type `r` (the connection string in our case) and it'll give you back some monad of type `m a`.

In the `postReservationIO` implementation we are passing `(postReservation req)` as the first argument to the `runReaderT` function. `(postReservation req)` has the type

```
(MonadReader ConnectionString m, MonadIO m) => m (HttpResult ())
```

which as far as I can tell is not a `ReaderT` so I'm struggling to understand how this works.

Can anyone explain how we have made the jump from something of type `(MonadReader ConnectionString m, MonadIO m) => m (HttpResult ())` to `ReaderT k r m a` in order to eliminate the `MonadReader` constraint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `m` in `postReservation`s type gets instantiated to `ReaderT * ConnectionString IO (HttpResult ())`, which is an instance of both `MonadReader ConnectionString` and `MonadIO`.

Note that `ReaderT` is only explicitly mentioned through `runReaderT`. It's that function that demands its argument to be a concrete `ReaderT` instead of an arbitrary `MonadReader ConnectionString`.

**Edit**:

As @Benjamin Hodgson points out, the underlying mechanisms are that of return type polymorphism, or more generally unification.

So, when the body of `postReservationIO` is type-checked, this is roughly what happens:

```
-- What we know, because we already type-checked them (this is necessary information about free variables):
runReaderT                               :: ReaderT k r m a -> r -> m a
postReservation req                      :: (MonadReader ConnectionString m', MonadIO m') => m' (HttpResult ())
connStr                                  :: ConnectionString

-- What we want to check
runReaderT (postReservation req) connStr :: IO (HttpResult ())

-- Unifying `runReaderT` with its arguments results in the following constraints:
-- First argument
ReaderT k r m a ~ (MonadReader ConnectionString m', MonadIO m') => m' (HttpResult ())
-- Second argument
r ~ ConnectionString
-- Return type
m (HttpResult ()) ~ IO (HttpResult ())
```

Read `~` as 'has to unify with'. E.g., the fact that the second argument to `runReaderT` is a `ConnectionString` necessitates that the type variable `r` unifies with `ConnectionString`.

The constraint `ReaderT k r m a ~ (MonadReader ConnectionString m', MonadIO m') => m' (HttpResult ())` is what I was alluding to earlier. This is what instantiates `m'` to `ReaderT * ConnectionString m`, which is further instantiated to `ReaderT * ConnectionString IO` as a result of the the last constraint.

It is only after all type variable constraints are satisfied that GHC checks that `ReaderT * ConnectionString IO` satisfies `MonadReader ConnectionString` and `MonadIO`, which indeed it does.

If this wasn't the case, e.g. when `postReservation :: (MonadLogger m, MonadIO m) => ReservationRendition -> m (HttpResult ())`, then the compiler wouldn't be able to find the instance `MonadLogger (ReaderT * ConnectionString IO)` and complain.

Comment: Good answer, which would be even better with a discussion of how return type polymorphism works :)

Comment: When you say the `m` in `postReservations` type gets instantiated to `ReaderT * ConnectionString IO (HttpResult ())` is this just a specialisation of the `MonadReader` instance for `ReaderT` i.e. `Monad m => MonadReader r (ReaderT * r m)`?

Comment: Exactly. In our case, `m ~ IO`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help